# How can I remove line shadows on Live Chart line chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

[image]

I created a line chart using a live chart. But I cannot eliminate the shadows (shaded areas in the image) under these lines.

```
 LineSeries yeni = new LineSeries();
            yeni.PointGeometrySize = 20;
            yeni.LineSmoothness = 0;
           // yeni.BitmapEffect.
         //   yeni.PointForeground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
            yeni.Title = kisiler[i].ToString();
            yeni.Values = new ChartValues<double>(allValues);
            cartesianChart1.Series.Add(yeni);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way I solved the problem:

```
yeni.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
```